# Error "Index vectors are of different classes: numeric date"

Tags: r

I am trying to implement the following code from the following site:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(timeDate)

symbols <- read.csv("sp500.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
nrStocks <- length(symbols[,1])

z <- zoo()
for (i in 1:nrStocks) {
  cat("Downloading ", i, " out of ", nrStocks , "\n")
  x <- get.hist.quote(instrument = symbols[i,], start = dateStart,
    quote = "AdjClose", retclass = "zoo", quiet = T)
  z <- merge(z, x)
}
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MFE&a=0&b=01&c=2008&d=8&e=12&f=2011&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=MFE&x=.csv'
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

In merge.zoo(z, x) : Index vectors are of different classes: numeric Date
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a list of possible issues:

- `"sp500.csv"`: You need to get this file from somewhere.  If you have taken this code from [here](http://blog.quanttrader.org/tag/downloading-data/) then one possibility is [this](http://blog.quanttrader.org/wp-content/uploads/sp500.csv) but that list is out of date
- `z <- zoo()`: This will not have the index in Date format and so causes the merge warnings, so might sensibly be followed by a line like `index(z) <- as.Date(format(time(z)),tz="")`
- `start = dateStart,`: You have not specified `dateStart`.  If you want the last month or so then something like `start = Sys.Date() - 30,` might work
- Wrong ticker symbols: The error message shows your list contained `MFE` as one of the symbols.  MFE was McAfee Inc, which has been taken over by Intel Corp and so no longer has a quoted share price.

Answer (score 2):

1. Wikipedia allows you to make a more accurate list for sp500.csv
2. There is an issue with yahoo dates

a. This will work when the markets in US are open.

b. This will probably not work when the markets in US are closed

The complete reference for get.hist.quote can be fount here
http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=tseries:get.hist.quote,
it did not bring me any help either,
After that I looked at the data outside market opening hours:
The first downloaded instrument is MMM, the first couple of lines are here (when the market is closed):

```
:Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-07-16,88.10,88.55,87.78,88.10,2120700,88.10
2012-07-16,88.12,88.65,87.77,88.10,2848100,88.10
2012-07-13,86.32,87.83,86.32,87.59,2599300,87.59
```

the first two lines appear to be identical.
For another instrument, while the markets are open (European instrument), 
this was not an issue.

```
x <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "^GDAXI", start = dateStart,
    quote = "AdjClose", retclass = "zoo", quiet = T)
```

For the DAX the data is below (now is 11H45 CET):

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-07-17,6583.77,6610.26,6583.57,6593.82,000,6565.72
2012-07-16,6550.95,6577.06,6511.18,6565.72,20388100,6565.72
```

Looked through the zoo.pdf manual (dated: February 14, 2012):

They suggest to resolve this by adding a line:

```
x <- aggregate(x, identity, mean) # for an average
```

or

```
x <- aggregate(x, identity, tail) # for the last observation
```

Have not completed my testing but this appears to do the trick without warnings and errors so far

Answer (score 0):

Code to make an accurate list of S&P500 symbols based on the Wikipedia information:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
sp500html <- getURL(url)
sp500 <- readHTMLTable(sp500html, stringsAsFactors = F)[[1]][,1]
```